# Printing an image from center of screen in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I'm working on a simple html project where I have 2560 x 1440 image and in the center of the image is basically the part of the image that needs to be shown, the rest of it is just to fill any screen resolution.

Here is the current code:

```
<img style="position: fixed; bottom:0; left:0;" src="footer.jpg"/>
```

and the CSS:

```
img {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

the problem here is that it prints the image left >to> right

would it be possible to have the image being printed from it's center and out.
So basically the image should still be at the bottom of the pages as the code does but I want the image to printed from it's center.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to center align the image in the

```
    {
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-top:-25px;
   margin-left:-25px;
   }
```

Comment: Sorry my fault, I wasn't specific enough. I want the image to remain at the bottom of the page, but I want it to be printed from the images center. So basically the center of the image will be at the bottom center of the screen no matter what screen size.